# How to use QZ decomposition for single matrix in Matlab?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, matrix-factorization

Can I use QZ decomposition on a single square matrix in Matlab?
Like,

```
[Aa,Q,Z]=qz(A);
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, QZ decomposition is given **for two matrices**, so that for $A,B\in \mathbb F^{n \times n}$:
$$
A=QSZ^*, B=QTZ^*
\tag{1}
\label{QZ}
$$
where $Q,Z^*$ are unitary, and $S,T$ are upper-triangular, and $\mathbb F$ is the field (real $\mathbb R$ or complex $\mathbb C$). QZ decomposition is usually called [generalized Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition#Generalized_Schur_decomposition).

**For a single matrix** $A\in\mathbb F^{n\times n}$, one would simply computes [Shur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition): 
$$
A=Q_\text{Schur}UQ^*_\text{Schur}
\tag{2}
\label{Schur}
$$
where $Q_\text{Schur}$ is unitary, and $U$ is upper triangular.

So the Schur decomposition $\eqref{Schur}$, allows "more restricted" decomposition of $A$, since there is no matrix $B$, which presence would result in a generalized QZ decomposition $\eqref{QZ}$ and a presence of $Z$.

---

In Matlab, [Schur decomposition](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/schur.html) $\eqref{Schur}$ can be computed, as follows:

```
[Q,U] = schur(A,...)
```

Take a look at Matlab function help for some additional computation options. Notice a confusion between Wikipedia and this post notation choice, compared to the Matlab help page.